# Server Error Resource cannot be found 404 when trying to access directory using HTTPS on IIS 8.5 but works using HTTP

Tags: c#, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I set up a new app in my preexisting Site in IIS (version 8.5) Windows server 2012 R2. All works fine when accessing the new directory using HTTP but when I try HTTPS it finds the initial directory but if I try to go to any of the registered routes it throws a "HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly".

I have wasted a lot of time on this issue and am unable to find the issue here. The bindings on the site work just fine for the rest of the apps.

I'm thinking that the issue may be in the web.config in the service endpoint but all changes I make don't seem to lead anywhere useful.

Important to note that what I'm setting up is almost a direct copy of another app running on the same IIS site minus some of the routes and the app pool it is in.

If anyone can offer a path I can take with getting SSL to work for this It would be extremely useful.

Comment: I suggest you dive into the sites and bindings once again, by using Binding Diagnostics, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html That should reveal who handles the HTTPS requests and gives you the 404 messages. Probably another site (and its binding) takes precedence and handles the request instead of your expected one.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get this to work setting my bindingConfiguration security mode to "Transport" it was originally set to "None" I'm not really sure why this was causing it to not work though.

Comment: of you found the cause, post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in the bindingConfiguration that was being used for the endpoint in the web.config had to be changed from security mode="None" => security mode="Transport"

I also needed to update the "mex" binding from binding="mexHttpBinding" => binding="mexHttpsBinding"